# What is the Haldane Hamiltonian for a sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

The general form for the Haldane Hamiltonian is $H(x)=a_0(x)+\vec{a}(\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{\sigma}$ for a 2-level system, where $\vec{a}(\vec{x})$ is a 3D vector. The hamiltonian can be simplified to
\begin{equation}
H(\vec{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} a_0(\vec{x})+a_3(\vec{x}) & a_1(\vec{x})-ia_2(\vec{x}) \\ a_1(\vec{x})+ia_2(\vec{x})& a_0(\vec{x})-a_3(\vec{x})\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

If the system was in spherical coordinates, rather than in cartesian coordinates, how would the Hamiltonian change?

My instincts are that the change would be irrelevant, since we are still dealing with components of $\vec{a}$ that are each functions of $\vec{x}$. In other words, changing coordinate systems would have no visible effect on the Hamiltonian as it is currently constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the change of coordinates would lead to a change in the functions of coordinates, i.e. $a_0$ and $\vec a$. The Hamiltonian should not change form.

Comment: So to follow up,  if I wanted to find the Berry curvatures of this Hamiltonian, I'd have to carry all of the different components of a around?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this concept.

Comment: The Berry curvature is the curl of $-i<u_n(x)|\nabla u_n(x)>$ where $|u_n(x)>$ are the eigenvectors.

Comment: This is small enough you can write down the eigenvectors explicitly in terms of the a's. When the a's change plug in differently. Just keep track of where the eigenvalues meet and avoid that part. Also easily solved in terms of a's.

Comment: @Kernloffland Well, I believe you should just diagonalize the given Hamiltonian in terms of the a's and after determining the eigenfunctions it should be an easy enough task to calculate the Berry curvature. Note that you will also have to use the spherical form of $\nabla$.